# How to stop Windows 10 virus cloud access?

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 notifies my that I should enable cloud access for the virus protection.
[image]
But I can not deactivate it. I can press cancel and this solves the issue. But after the next reboot of Windows it notifies again and again.

Comment: Why not just allow it access, so it can do its job?

Comment: Open the Windows Security center and click on Settings (lower left).  Look under Security Providers and turn off Web Protection.  That should turn Cloud off.